# C# - Code supposed to be unreachable when calculate value in LINQ sum method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, nhibernate

I want to fill a view model with data from a nHibernate IQueryable. But I have a problem with the calculation in the sum method.
I've tried several things. At first there was a Math.Round on two decimal digits around the calculation. This works fine:

```
var documents = DocumentService.GetAll().WithSearchRequest(searchModel);

var document = from docs in documents
                  let taxAmount = docs.Positions.Sum(p => Math.Round(p.Amount * (p.TaxRate / 100M), 2))
                  let grossAmount = docs.Positions.Sum(p => p.Amount) + taxAmount
                  select new OverviewViewModel
                  {
                     Id = docs.Id,
                     TaxAmount = taxAmount,
                     GrossAmount = grossAmount,
                  };
```

When I remove this Math.Round, I get a "Code supposed to be unreachable" exception:
    var documents = DocumentService.GetAll().WithSearchRequest(searchModel);

```
var document = from docs in documents 
                  let taxAmount = docs.Positions.Sum(p => p.Amount * (p.TaxRate / 100M))
                  let grossAmount = docs.Positions.Sum(p => p.Amount) + taxAmount
                  select new OverviewViewModel
                  {
                     Id = docs.Id,
                     TaxAmount = taxAmount,
                     GrossAmount = grossAmount,
                  };
```

When I remove the division with 100, it works well. It works also fine when I replace the 100 with another decimal variable which is not a constant. So the problem seems to be the division with a constant. 
All values are decimal, I tried to cast them to float or double, but nothing solves the problem.

InnerException is null. Here is the stacktrace:

```
   bei System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   bei System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteUnaryExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   bei System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   bei System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpressionFreeTemps(Expression expression, Stack stack)
   bei System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda)
   bei System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(StackSpiller spiller)
   bei System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
   bei System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile()
   bei NHibernate.Linq.ExpressionToHqlTranslationResults.MergeLambdasAndCompile[TDelegate](IList`1 itemTransformers)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.ExpressionToHqlTranslationResults..ctor(HqlTreeNode statement, IList`1 itemTransformers, IList`1 listTransformers, IList`1 postExecuteTransformers, List`1 additionalCriteria)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.IntermediateHqlTree.GetTranslation()
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitSubQueryExpression(SubQueryExpression expression)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitUnaryExpression(UnaryExpression expression)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.SelectClauseVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   bei Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssigment)
   bei Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding memberBinding)
   bei Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitList[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 list, Func`2 visitMethod)
   bei Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberBindingList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 expressions)
   bei Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberInitExpression(MemberInitExpression expression)
   bei Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.SelectClauseVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.SelectClauseVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitSelectClause(SelectClause selectClause, QueryModel queryModel)
   bei Remotion.Linq.Clauses.SelectClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel)
   bei Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, Boolean filter)
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   bei NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   bei NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   bei NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   bei NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   bei Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   bei Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.Execute[TModel,TResult](IQueryable source, Func`2 selector)
   bei Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.CreateDataSourceResult[TModel,TResult](IQueryable queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState, Func`2 selector)
   bei Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(IQueryable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request)
   bei Web.Modules.Controllers.DocumentController.ReadDocuments(DataSourceRequest request, DocumentSearchViewModel searchModel) in C:\Modules\Invoicing\Controllers\DocumentController.cs:Zeile 624.
   bei lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   bei System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

What is the problem with the LINQ sum?

Comment: It looks like an issue with nhibernate rather than linq. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Perhaps try to clean up the expression ``(decimal)(p.Amount * (p.TaxRate / 100M))``: if ``p.TaxRate`` is already of type decimal, the type cast at the beginning should not be needed (if ``p.Amount`` is not decimal, cast that). Otherwise, if ``p.TaxRate`` is double, try dividing by 100.0 instead.

Comment: @KevinGosse we are not. I will try it with the latest version and let you know when the issue also exists.

Comment: @dumetrulo Amount and TaxRate are both decimal. I removed the unnecessary cast but the problem still exists

Comment: @KevinGosse With nHibernate version 5.1.3 it works fine. So the problem seems to be our old nHibernate version. We try to update asap. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is our old nHibernate version. With the version 5.1.3 it works.